# Transaction and nested method call

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have this code

A call is done to `updatePerson` method

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class PersonManager {

    @Transactional
    public void updatePerson(PersonPayload personPayload, String uid) {
        Person person = personRepository.findByUid(uid);

        personProcessManager.createLog(person);

        Person personDuplicate = new Person();
        personDuplicate.copyPerson(person);

        personMapper.updatePerson(personPayload,personDuplicate);

        personRepository.save(person);

        personRepository.save(personDuplicate);

        personProcessManager.createLog(personDuplicate);

    }

}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class PersonProcessManager {

    @Transactional
    public Log createLog(Person person) {
        return createLog(person,
                LogTypeEnum.CHANGE.getId(),
                LogStatusEnum.COPY.getId());
    }

    private Log createLog(Person person, Long logTypeId, Long statusLogId) {
        Log log = new Log();
        log.setLogType(1);
        log.setLogStatus(2);
        log.setDateCreation(LocalDate.now());
        log.setPerson(person);
        return logRepository.save(person);
    }

}
```

if an error happens in the private method of `createLog` is there any rollback that will happen?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you'll set it up.

Let's see how nested transactions actually work: Spring has a transaction manager that maintains and pushes all nested transactions into the stack and after the nested transaction is finished it'll pop out.

Another good thing to know is that `@Transactional` attribute by default uses the propagation of the error back to the parent which is called `REQUIRED`.

In order to fine-tune the `Transactional` attribute you need to add the propagation attribute `@Transactional(propagation =Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` to the annotation. You can read more about [transactional propagations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation#transaction-propagations).

In your specific case:

- the error occurred in private `createLog`
- sends the error to public `createLog`
- the transaction of public `PersonProcessManager.createLog`  rolled-back
- propagated error to the parent which is a public `updatePerson`
- the transaction of public `PersonManager.updatePerson`  rolled-back
- all transactions rolled-back
- the error will be thrown/propagated further in the chain

Comment: where do you want to put @Transactional(propagation =Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve. There are a few other propagation strategies in the link that I provided. With the `REQUIRES_NEW` strategy you don't propagate the error to the parent transaction. This means that the current transaction will be rolled back but the parent won't know about the previously failed transaction. In your example: if you add `REQUIRES_NEW` to `PersonProcessManager.createLog` then `log` won't be stored but `person` will be stored/updated (of course if no other errors will be raised in `PersonManager.updatePerson`)